# How to add path (to dll) to Qt Creator project?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, qmake

I have a Qt Creator project, its a Windows application. It depends on some libraries I installed using vcpkg and others.

I managed to set `INCLUDEPATH` to add `.h` search path on the project file. And similarly I set `LIB` so it finds the `.lib` files. Since this is on the `.pro` file and I have it on git configuration is done once.

Then to run, I go to `Run Settings` and edit `Path` including path to the `.dll` files, so far so good. This configuration is kind of an issue because it is not on the `.pro` file and I have to set this path every time I get things from git.

Is there any way to set this (the path to search for dll files) on the `.pro` file?

Answer (score 0):

You may add the below clause to your pro file

```cpp
win32:LIBS += "C:/mydlls/mydll.dll"
```

or

```cpp
LIBS += "C:/mydlls/mydll.dll"
```

according to this [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs)

Comment: Isn't that for `.lib` files?Should it work for `.dll` also?

Comment: This also works for a DLL. I tested  on Windows 7 using VMWare (as I only have Linux on my PC). Did you test?

Comment: I can only find documentation saying it works with lib, do you know of any documentation saying it should work with dll?

Comment: You may have some information here : https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application